# Suggestions for projects related to network monitoring, documentation, collaboration

Tags: untagged

I am looking for any projects integrating functions like monitoring, management and documentation of network/servers/services.

Currently using Orion and Nagios for tasks on monitoring and alerts, the documentation is left to the spreedsheets, and management is of course manual or scripted one-offs on the cli's.

Also this is for a small/midsize ISP/Telco with Cisco, *nix and some Windows Servers.

Comment: Aren't we all?  Sadly... there's not 1 all-powerful tool that does everything the way we want.  Several have tried... but they all fail in one way or another.

Comment: Well in that case, I would add an addedum. If there is none all-in-one, then which project out there comes close? -thanks

Comment: +1 to CompWiz, in addition I've found the best combination tends to be a few tools that focus on one area (like Monitoring) and doing it extremely well.

Comment: @notmyname: First... your addendum is just repeating your initial question... which is... "what tool will do my job for me... and make buttered-toast too."   The answer is very simple.   "The one that does what you need it to do."

Comment: Ask a general question... get a general answer.

Comment: So no current projects are known to do this or anything close? -thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'One tool to rule them all' probably doesn't exist, and probably isn't even a good idea. For monitoring, Nagios is decent, but you might want to take a look at the [Planet DevOps](http://www.planetdevops.net/) blog... excellent coverage of the state of open-source monitoring software. Newer options such as Graphite, Monit, etc. provide a lot of functionality, and are becoming easier to integrate.

The place you should focus, IMHO, is on supplementing your areas that seem to be weaker: documentation and management. [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) is a wonderful open-source tool for configuration management. It was originally very *nix-entric, but Windows support was added to recent releases. Definitely put an end to one-off scripts.

As for documentation, your documentation and collaboration tools should really be the same, so that documentation can evolve rather than become outdated, etc. A good CMS should allow you to do both. You could also take a look at [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/) (a fork of Redmine) which combines features such as an issue tracker, wiki, source repository management, document management, and more into an integrated and easy to install/manage project. I use this every day and it makes life MUCH easier. It also exposes a REST API as well as a plugin architecture that makes it easy to integrate with other systems.

It might take a few tools, but you can easily combine them to have a solid, collaborative system to document, monitor, and manage your infrastructure. But rather than trying to a single, monolithic tool, build the toolkit appropriate for your situation.